# How does C++ handle const marked passed-by-reference classes, that aren't changed directly but from the other side?

Tags: c++

So I am making a Chess Engine right now, and I have a Game class containing an Advantage object, and I am using an odd method to modify them. It involves the Game class calling a member function for the Advantage class, and it passes itself by reference to the Advantage class, and is marked as const. I am now getting some errors that I didn't used to, and decided I didn't really understand fully how this was working. So here's some pseudocode, can someone explain it to me?

```
class Game ;
class Advantage {
private:
    bool whiteWinning_ = true;
public:
    void updateAdvantage(const Game& game);
}
class Game {
private:
    Advantage advantage_;
    int pawnLocation_ = 1; //obviously, this isn't a real chess game, but still...
public:
    void makeMove(int pawnSteps);
    bool getWinning() const;
}

void Advantage::updateAdvantage(const Game& game){
    //Game is marked const, but the same object is changed because advantage_ is being changed???
    whiteWinning_ = game.getWinning();
}

void Game::makeMove(int pawnSteps) {
    pawnLocation_ += pawnsteps;
    advantage_.updateAdvantage(*this);
}

bool Game::getWinning() const {
    return pawnLocation_ >= 8;
}
```

Comment: What are the errors? I don't see any problem with the code above. The member function `Advantage::updateAdvantage` is not marked const so there is no issue with `whiteWinning_` being updated.

Comment: instead of chasing hypothetical errors, maybe point out actual.. or try narrow it down. If  they are run-time errors, some debugging is in order.

Answer (score 1):

The game object which is passed to `Advantage::updateAdvantage` is casting your argument to `const`. However the `Advantage` object in `Advantage::updateAdvantage` which is denoted as `this`  isn't const, thus allowing you writing to `whiteWinning_`.

Comment: Re: "casting your argument" -- there are no casts in this code. At the point of the all, the name of the object is **converted** to a `const` reference. A cast is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. +1.

Comment: You are defintly wrong. casting might be something you see in code in case of explicit cast, but you might have a cast which bot appear in code its called implicit cast.

Comment: You're right that "implicit cast" is commonly used by beginners to describe an **implicit conversion**. Nevertheless, a cast is something you write in your source code. There is no such thing as an implicit cast.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Yep! But whiteWinning_ being changed effectively modifies the object that is the same as being pointed to by const Game& game, and that's okay because that value is seperate??

Comment: The const occupies `game` object. `whiteWinning_ ` is  an `Advantage` class member however the `this` in this context is non const